# For an idempotent matrix $A$, how do you show that $\text{Null($A$)} \cap \text{Row($A$)} = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is an idempotent matrix, having the property $A^2 = A$.

I am trying to show that the intersection of its null space and row space is equal to the zero vector, but I am having difficulty thinking of how to start.

If anyone would be willing to help me out I would really appreciate it.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Include *some* work. E.g. begin with describing these two subspaces and their intersection, for any $A.$

Comment: Thanks Anne! Will do.

Comment: [Don't delete and repost your question!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31573). Instead, Edit it to improve it (click on the "Edit" button below the tags of your post).

Answer (score -1):

You want to show that a particular vector space is zero, i.e. the space only contains the zero vector. So the overall idea is to take an arbitrary vector in that space, and show that it is in fact the zero vector. The rest, you should try yourself.

Comment: Thanks Joshua! I will try that out.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Dear @AnneBauval, may I ask the best way to carry on from this point onwards? Is it to delete the question and ask a new one following the guideline?

Comment: It seems like you're asking me to not help this person who has asked, reasonably, for a hint?

Comment: Indeed, per the links recalled above (to you and to the OP) about the rules of this site and the advices helping to follow them.